# Local install GitLab Pages - 404

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I have a local installation of Gitlab-ce and I have enabled gitlab-pages using the simplest setup.

- Added an A record to point to the server running Gitlab
- edited `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` to contain `pages_external_url 'http://gitlab.mydomain.com'`
- reconfigure

However, when I visit the link after deploying pages I get a 404 page.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done the pre-requisites of https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/ ?

Comment: @Rekovni if I understand the prerequisites correctly I need a root domain like say `mygtpages.com` pointing to the server and not `pages.gitlab.mydomain.com?`

Comment: Yes, so for example, gitlab use `gitlab.com` for their main server, and `gitlab.io` [for pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html).

Comment: That did not solve my problem. I created an internal zone `glpages.local` and had that pointed to the server running gitlab also on `gitlab.mydomain.com`. The resulting link after building the pipeline looks like `project.glpages.local/something`. visiting the link re-route to gitlab.mydomain.com and I get the 404.